# QLineEdit change PlaceholderText color

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qlineedit

I have a LineEdit widget in an app and its PlaceholderText changes based on the user's input. However, I'd like for the PlaceholderText to look like normal text, i.e. to be black instead of grey.

I've looked online but most of the results were either not precise enough for me to understand them or using different languages than Python, which makes it hard for me to implement the solution in my script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the color of the placeholderText then you have to use the QPalette:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets


def main():

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(placeholderText="Stack Overflow")

    pal = w.palette()
    text_color = pal.color(QtGui.QPalette.Text)
    # or
    # text_color = QtGui.QColor("black")
    pal.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.PlaceholderText, text_color)
    w.setPalette(pal)

    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: very nice solution